# How to do log with 0 values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I apply numpy log function to a panda dataframe that has 0 values in it?

This is an example of the series inside the dataframe I want to transform

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CoapplicantIncome': [0, 1508.0, 0, 2358.0, 0],
                   'ApplicantIncome': [5849, 4583, 3000, 2583, 6000]})


    ApplicantIncome  CoapplicantIncome

0             5849                0.0
1             4583             1508.0
2             3000                0.0
3             2583             2358.0
4             6000                0.0
```

I tried to use

```
df['CoapplicantIncome'] = np.log(df['CoapplicantIncome'])
```

but it says 'cannot convert float NaN to integer'

After I do some searching, I've come to this line of code that says it will handle the 0 values.

```
df['CoapplicantIncome'] = np.log(df['CoapplicantIncome'].replace(0, np.nan))
```

But it still says 'cannot convert float NaN to integer'. So how can I solve this?

Interestingly, if I build this dataframe from scratch using `pd.DataFrame`the problem does not occur, but if I read the dataframe from a csv file, then the problem occur.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log` but not the same issue. What verion of `pandas`?

Comment: @qräbnö edited with additional information

Comment: @roganjosh i'm using pandas version 0.20.3 and numpy version 1.13.3

Comment: Same pandas version as me. Your issue isn't reproducible from your example. Presumably you have a `NaN` in there

Comment: Throws a warning but runs ok in pandas `0.23`

Comment: @RafaelC ah right, cheers, I updated my pandas and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this problem by updating my pandas version.